# Как узнать user_id python telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать админ панель через телеграмм диалог, а для этого нужна проверка юзер айди, подскажите как ее сделать

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5226540618:AAFaTMrlXWuE2tJH64EjMvEANJ_AnBIHAJY')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message('Ваш айди: ', user_id)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю где-то так

`if message.from_user.id == 12345: ...`

Ну а ещё можно сделать список со всеми айди

```
admins = [12341, 24422]
if message.from_user.id in admins: 
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

> Как узнать user_id python telegram

```
message.chat.id
```

> для этого нужна проверка юзер айди, подскажите как ее сделать

```
if message.chat.id == <id админа>:
   pass
```

Comment: Нужно ```if message.from_user.id == <id админа>```